# Launching an Angular project

Tags: angular-cli

I'm studying Angular. I created a small project in IDEA. I run it with the command

```
ng serve --open
```

I have a few questions

1. In order for me to run it on another computer, what files do I need to transfer there? I can't move the whole project.
2. I understand correctly that Node is quite enough for this project to work.js or is it better to use a different server?
3. I want this project to be running all the time, i.e. started at the start of Windows.    How it is done correctly.
   Run the **ng server** command every time, or can it be somehow uploaded to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The CLI command `ng serve` has been created for development use only.

To host your application on a server you have to use `ng build` command and then take the generated static files and host them where you desire.

Read the docs first: [Angular | Basic Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#basic-deployment-to-a-remote-server)

*PS: I usually host my angular apps with nginx:  [Deploy Angular Apps with Nginx](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/deploy-angular-apps-nginx)*